# how to send an id value from a gridView to the database?

Tags: javascript, .net, gridview

I have a GridView on a .aspx page with a hidden column which has an ID value. When the user clicks on a certain row, I need the ID column value on the C# code behind, so that I can query the database and populate another view with data corresponding to this ID. My problem is, I can pass this ID value to a javascript function in the onClick event of the row, but how do I get it to the code behind from where I can actually query the SQL Server database?

Comment: Please tell us what technology stack your using and also show your existing code.

Comment: I'm not sure what code to show, it's just a simple grid view. I've edited the answer to add some technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it -

Got the selected row index with -
**e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView2, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);**

In the SelectedIndexChanged event of the Grid -
 **GridView2.SelectedRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
 string id = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;**

Where, Cells[0] was my hidden column which contains the ID value

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  datakeynames property of the datagrid control specifying the column containing the ID

```
<asp:gridview 
id="grvTest" 
autogeneratecolumns="true" 
datakeynames="ID" 
runat="server">
```

//get the value of the selected row

```
void grvTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
// Determine the index of the selected row.
int index = CustomersGridView.SelectedIndex;


//Display the primary key value of the selected row.
 Message.Text = "The key value of the selected row is " +
    grvTest.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd suggest based on the information you've provided.

Just to clarify, you said that "when the user clicks on a certain **row**, you want the ID **column** value...". Is this correct or did you mean to say that you wanted the row value?

Either way, the same basic rules apply.

Here is an example from CodeProject that outlines what you need to do.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50080/Extended-ASP-NET-GridView-with-cell-click-events